# epstopdf and graphicspath with pdflatex

Tags: epstopdf

If I have an eps file in a subfolder and point to it with graphicspath, it can't seem to do the conversion, the log says:

```
(epstopdf)             Output file: </path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=/path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf /path/to/image/img.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 72.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=/path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf /path/to/image/img.eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: </path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

./chapters/results2.tex:72: Package pdftex.def Error: File `/path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

If I run `epstopdf --outfile=/path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf /path/to/image/img.eps` it works fine. If I run the same command with `repstopdf`, it returns:

```
!!! Error: Output filename '/path/to/image/img-eps-converted-to.pdf' not allowed in restricted mode.
```

Running `ls -ld /path/to/image` returns:

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

**Files for example:**

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[maintest.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{/path/to/image/}}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=/path/to/image/} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{img.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

maintest.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\subfile{chapters/test}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

mystyle.tex:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

Answer (score 2):

Running external programs is a security risk. Therefore the default settings are a compromise. Some more or less secure programs (hopefully more "more") are allowed. This is called the restricted shell escape mode. `epstopdf` is too powerful, it can overwrite arbitrary files. Therefore, a restricted version `repstopdf` was created, which follows the policy of `texmf.cnf`,
which restricts the writing of output files, from `texmf.cnf` of TeX Live 2015:

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a

% Write .log/.dvi/etc. files here, if the current directory is unwritable.
%TEXMFOUTPUT = /tmp
```

In your case, the output file name starts with "/", thus it is an absolute file name and variable `TEXMFOUTPUT` is probably not set.

Possible solutions/workarounds:

- Since the files are in sub folders of the current working directory, try relative file names instead.
- TeX Live's `epstopdf-sys.cfg` as provided by the package author (me) sets the program name to `repstopdf` if restricted shell escape was detected. In case of full shell escape, `epstopdf` is used. Thus you can also run your project with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: I should have added that the command seems to work for some directories, but not for others.

Comment: @James Absolute directories are forbidden (unless listed in `TEXMFOUTPUT`) in the default restricted shell escape mode.